# Java adding validation to my code

Tags: java, validation, loops

@pablo
I seem to be stuck in this loop :

```
do{
            System.out.println("Voulez-vous saisir d'autres parties? (o/n)");             
            reponse = niveau.nextLine();  // extraction de la dernière ligne 
            if (reponse.toLowerCase().equals("o") == false || reponse.toUpperCase().equals("O") == false || reponse.toLowerCase().equals("n") == false || reponse.toUpperCase().equals("N") == false)  {
            System.out.println("R\u00C9PONSE INVALIDE ! VEUILLEZ ENTRER O OU N.");
            } else {
            validationReponse = true;
            }
        }while(!validationReponse);
```

Thank you all for your help ! I was able to get the validation working for questions with numeric answers but now I don't know how to get it working for questions with a "y or n" answer.  I tried this but it's not working :

```
do{
            System.out.println("Do you want to enter more game scores ? (y/n)");             
            reponse = niveau.nextLine();   
            if (reponse != o || reponse != n) {
            System.out.println("Answer is invalid! Please enter y or n.");
            } else {
                validationReponse = true;
            }
        }while(!validationReponse);
```

---

I am a beginner.  I am taking my first java class. In my code, I would like to add a validation for the questions : Please choose a game level, Have you won the game and Do you want to enter more games, I need to make sure that the input is valid and if an invalid answer is provided, it needs to loop back to the question.  I am not sure how to do that.
No advanced coding in your answers please.  I am in a beginners class.  It needs to be simple.

```
String reponse="O";                     

    while (reponse.toLowerCase().equals("o"))      
    { 
                           System.out.println("Please choose your game level :"); 
        System.out.println (" ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++");               
        System.out.println (" For Beginner press 1"); 
        System.out.println (" For Advanced press 2"); 
        System.out.println (" For Expert press 3"); 
        System.out.println (" ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++");  
        System.out.print (" My choice is : ");

        Niveau = niveau.nextInt();

        if(Niveau == 1){

                int choix1 = 0; 
                nbParties_Facile++;         
                System.out.println("Have you won the game ?");                 
                System.out.println("     Press 1 for YES "); 
                System.out.println("     Press 2 for NO "); 

                choix1 = niveau.nextInt(); 
                niveau.nextLine();  

                    if (choix1 == 1){

                    nbPartiesFaciles_Finies++;
                    tauxReussite_Facile = nbPartiesFaciles_Finies / nbParties_Facile * 100;
                    System.out.println("How many times did you take to complete the grid ?");
                    System.out.println("     Please enter the time in minutes");
                    String afficheur5 = niveau.nextLine();
                    tempsResolution_Facile = (nbPartiesFaciles_Finies * tempsResolution_Facile) + Integer.parseInt(afficheur5) / (nbPartiesFaciles_Finies);
                    }
                    else if (choix1 == 2){
                    tauxReussite_Facile = nbPartiesFaciles_Finies - 1 / nbParties_Facile * 100;
                    }
                    else {
                    //default
                    }
        }

        if(Niveau == 2){

                int choix2 = 0; 
                nbParties_Intermediaire++;            
                System.out.println("Have you won the game ?");                 
                System.out.println("     Press 1 for YES "); 
                System.out.println("     Press 2 for NO "); 

                choix2 = niveau.nextInt();  
                niveau.nextLine();  

                    if (choix2 == 1){

                    nbPartiesIntermediaires_Finies++;
                    tauxReussite_Intermediaire = nbPartiesIntermediaires_Finies / nbParties_Intermediaire * 100;
                    System.out.println("How many times did you take to complete the grid ?");
                    System.out.println("     Please enter the time in minutes");
                    String afficheur7 = niveau.nextLine();
                    tempsResolution_Intermediaire = (nbPartiesIntermediaires_Finies * tempsResolution_Intermediaire) + Integer.parseInt(afficheur7) / (nbPartiesIntermediaires_Finies);
                    }
                    else if (choix2 == 2){
                    tauxReussite_Intermediaire = nbPartiesIntermediaires_Finies - 1 / nbParties_Intermediaire * 100;
                    }
                    else {
                    //default
                    }
        } 

        if(Niveau == 3){

                int choix3 = 0; 
                nbParties_Expert++;            
                System.out.println("Have you won the game ?");                 
                System.out.println("     Press 1 for YES "); 
                System.out.println("     Press 2 for NO "); 

                choix3 = niveau.nextInt();  
                niveau.nextLine();  

                    if (choix3 == 1){

                    nbPartiesExpertes_Finies++;
                    tauxReussite_Expert = nbPartiesExpertes_Finies / nbParties_Expert * 100;
                    System.out.println("How many times did you take to complete the grid ?");
                    System.out.println("     Please enter the time in minutes");
                    String afficheur9 = niveau.nextLine();
                    tempsResolution_Expert = (nbPartiesExpertes_Finies * tempsResolution_Expert) + Integer.parseInt(afficheur9) / (nbPartiesExpertes_Finies);
                    }
                    else if (choix3 == 2){
                    tauxReussite_Expert = nbPartiesExpertes_Finies - 1 / nbParties_Expert * 100;
                    }
                    else {
                    //default
                    }
        } 

        System.out.println("Do you want to enter more games ? (o/n)");             
        reponse = niveau.nextLine();    

    } 

        niveau.close();
```

Comment: `response.toLowerCase().equals("o")` Can be replaced by `response.equalsIgnoreCase("o")` for simplicity and eligibility.

Comment: What does this do `niveau.nextLine();` ? I don't think you need that.

Comment: I think you are right for niveau.nextLine();  .  I will remove it.

Comment: Even though you're just starting with Java, it's a good idea to get into good habits regarding the naming of classes and variables. I'd recommend you read the [Java Naming Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html)

Comment: just out of curiosity what game is this ?

Answer (score 0):

Let's use as an example *Please choose a game level question*

So you there are many ways to do this, I will try to keep it as simple as possible since you are a beginner to the language, but the goal is always to stick to object orientated programming. However, we can accomplish this with a a simple method
. So you could have a simple method like this:

```
private static boolean askForLevel() {
    System.out.println("What is the level you want?");
    String response = scanner.nextLine();
    if (!response.equals("something")) {

        return false;
    }
    askForLevel();
    // More stuff
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Thank you all for your help ! Now if I need to validate a question where the answer is y or n, how to I do it ?  I tried this but it doesn't work !  if (reponse != y || reponse != n) {

Comment: Remember that for Strings you wants to use the method equals() to compare to strings, you would only use the != operator if you were comparing primitive data types. So for a String, response.equals("anotherstring")

Comment: I tried this but now I seem to be stuck in my loop :

Comment: do{
    System.out.println("Voulez-vous saisir d'autres parties? (o/n)");             
    reponse = niveau.nextLine();  // extraction de la dernière ligne 
    if (reponse.toLowerCase().equals("o") == false || reponse.toUpperCase().equals("O") == false || reponse.toLowerCase().equals("n") == false || reponse.toUpperCase().equals("N") == false)  {
    System.out.println("R\u00E9PONSE INVALIDE ! VEUILLEZ ENTRER O OU N.");
    } else {
    validationReponse = true;
    }
   }while(!validationReponse);

Comment: I tried to indent four spaces to add my code but it doesn't seem to work in the comments.  Sorry I am new on this forum.

Comment: @JarPO Can you send an updated copy of your code please?

Answer (score 0):

Do somwething as Below,

```
do {
        System.out.println("Please choose your game level :"); 
        System.out.println (" ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++");               
        System.out.println (" For Beginner press 1"); 
        System.out.println (" For Advanced press 2"); 
        System.out.println (" For Expert press 3"); 
        System.out.println (" ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++");  
        System.out.print (" My choice is : ");
        while (!sc.hasNextInt()) {
        System.out.println("That's not a number, Please choose a Number !");
        sc.next();  
    }
    number = sc.nextInt();
} while (number<=3);
```

inside `if(number==1)` do the thing same as above.

Answer (score 0):

I would use JOptionPane instead of scanner...but that's a matter of opinion. Since you are new, your teacher is probably not going to jump right into object-oriented programming, which is ok because you need to understand the basics, so with a minimal use of object-oriented programming:

```
   //user input
   int level = 0;
   do{
       level = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Choose the level :").trim());
     }while(level < 1 || level > 3);

    if (level == 1) {
       //your code
    }
    else if(level == 2){
       //your code
    }
    else if(level == 3){
       //your code
    }
```

You could build this in a private method like Pablo suggested.